# Get Github Actions Virtual Environment values

Tags: github-actions

In a Github action workflow, is there a way to access the "Set up Job" -> "Virtual Environment" values? Ideally, I'd like to get them from variables already present, but getting them from the output of a command would be just fine too.

I can see the values in the Github actions UI by clicking on a specific job, then "Set up Job", then expending "Virtual Environment".

```
Virtual Environment
  Environment: ubuntu-20.04
  Version: 20220425.1
  Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu20/20220425.1/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md
  Image Release: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/releases/tag/ubuntu20%2F20220425.1
```

I'd like to create a cache key based on that info so that, when it changes, the cache is made anew.

**Background:**

I have some tests that run on both `["ubuntu-latest", "macos-latest"]`. I also have a setup action that in part builds some shared libraries (which is slow) and caches them. The shared libraries are external though and only need to be rebuilt for updates to the runner image (or for new versions of the libraries, which isn't a concern). The current cache key is `${{ runner.os }}-${{ needs.setup.outputs.cache-key-suffix }}`, which only ever changes when we bump the `cache-key-suffix` hard-coded string. Using that key, the cache is shared among all the workflows and branches, saving lots of needless duplicated work.

**Deep Background:**

The specific problem I'm solving is that one of those shared libraries is Rocks DB. The tests were working fine for a while, but recently stopped; *most* tests using Rocks DB started failing with `signal: illegal instruction (core dumped)`. The only thing that might have changed is an update to `ubuntu-latest`. So I figure that it'd be nice to automatically have the cache recreated when that happens.

I've tried digging through the [Github Actions: Variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) and [Github Actions: Contexts](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#inputs-context) documentation, and some general Google-based research, but haven't been able to find a way to get those values for use in a workflow.